# is it possible to force "Zoom to Mouse Position" option to use previous mode's mouse position?

Tags: python

I do modeling  in edit mode and sculpt mode(or Object mode and Edit mode), but If I edit mesh in edit mode and start sculpting in sculpt mode, "Zoom to Mouse Position"  setting forget the mouse position which I set in  edit mode. Is there any way to make "Zoom to Mouse Position" to use previous mode's mouse position? Maybe python script can make it possible?